# shell script Move and Copy

Tags: linux, shell, syntax

I have a folder named rules in

```
/srv/www/htdocs/downloads
```

and I have another folder with the same name rules in here:

```
/srv/www/htdocs/didebansnort/core/snort/
```

I want to copy the folder rules in upper one to the second path

Also I want to know what is the syntax for moving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the same that you use when you copy/move things in shell. That's why they called shell scripts:)

**Copying** (from -> to)

```
cp -r /srv/www/htdocs/downloads/rules /srv/www/htdocs/didebansnort/core/snort/rules
```

we use **cp -r** to copy directory (r stands for recursive)
and simple **cp** for copying of a single file.

**Moving** (from -> to)

```
mv /srv/www/htdocs/downloads/rules /srv/www/htdocs/didebansnort/core/snort/rules
```

This is for nix/mac/cygwin

**P.S.**
While in the shell you can simply type in this to get a complete manual:

```
man command_name
```

Answer (score 1):

If the directory `/srv/www/htdocs/didebansnort/core/snort/rules` is not empty you cannot just move `/srv/www/htdocs/downloads/rules` to `/srv/www/htdocs/didebansnort/core/snort`. You'll either need to delete the existing directory or devise some merging strategy. Fore example, copying over `cp -r /srv/www/htdocs/downloads/rules /srv/www/htdocs/didebansnort/core/snort/rules` (as nix showed) will result in overwriting all duplicate files.