# Copy one directory to another directory , if target directory already exist? how to rename it using shell scripting?

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting
Copy one directory to another directory, if target directory already exist? how to rename target directory ?
 for example i have a directory (red) need to copy another directory (org), target directory (org) have already red directory at that time need to rename it.

using shell scripting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [shell script Move and Copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888830/shell-script-move-and-copy)

Answer (score 0):

Copy a directory even if it exists and recursively:

```
cp -rf source target
```

Rename a directory

```
mv oldname newname
```